# not able to run "sudo apt --fix-broken install" ..Please let me know the fix for the same

Tags: command-line, apt, server, dpkg, mysql

```
bhoopathi@it-Latitude-3510:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-core-8.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-core-8.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/18.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 136 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-core-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-apt-config' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 196862 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
**dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql/bulgarian/errmsg.sys', which is also in package percona-server-common 8.0.26-16-1.focal
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
```

Comment: Your output shows multiple problems. It is unclear which problem you are asking about, or which problem you want help with first.

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install percona-server-common-
```

will uninstall the conflicting package percona-server-common and probably fix the dependency problems. I could not find that package in standard Ubuntu repositories, so I suppose you have installed it from some third party repository.